# The frequency and the tuned circuit

Tags: capacitor, ac, frequency, homework

I came across this question in my text book, it says:

> The circuit shown in the figure is in resonance, what will happen to the impedance of the circuit when we increase the frequency of the source?

[image]

The answer was:

> The impedance decreases.

And I don't understand it, could you please explain it for me?

Comment: Questions with no attempt at a solution are closed.

Comment: I gave the solution which my text book present, I want to understand it, I have already the answer I don't want a solution I want an explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a series tuned RLC circuit, at resonance, the impedances of capacitor and inductor cancel leaving just the resistor. If the applied frequency rises above or falls below circuit resonance, the net impedance will rise: -

[image]

Comment: The impedance will rise?! That's not the book answer? Could you explain how will this happen in more details? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Quite simply and as unambiguously as I can state this, either the book answer is wrong or your interpretation of what the books says is wrong. My explanation contains ALL the details - which part do you not understand?

Comment: I understand your answer. In the book, it says that when increasing the frequency the reading of the ammeter will increase, so I guessed that the impedance will decrease.

Comment: The ammeter reading rises as frequency is raised from below resonance towards resonance. Above resonance, if you increase the frequency the ammeter reading lowers. This, of course, is different again for parallel tuned circuits.

Comment: Seems the book was wrong, but I got it, thank you!